# Amcharts 4 treemap add bullets to all childrens

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

How do I add bullets to all childrens in my treemap at once? I just found a way to do it for each level with:

```
var level1 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("0");
var level1_bullet = level1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
level1_bullet.locationY = 0.5;
level1_bullet.locationX = 0.5;
level1_bullet.label.text = "{name}";
level1_bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
```